# Show that a matrix satisfying certain conditions is non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, inverse, markov-process

I have a square matrix $A$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. The elements on the diagonal are negative;
2. All other elements are non-negative;
3. All row sums are less than or equal to $0$;
4. There is at least one row sum that is less than $0$.

I think that $A$ is non-singular, but I cannot prove it. I was thinking to try to show that $\det{A} \neq 0$ by determining that there is no eigenvalue that is zero. Can anyone point me to a book or sketch a proof (not necessarily the one I have in mind)?

---

**Edit 1** It seems that I am missing a condition. I will try to sketch the situation more closely. There are two more matrices $B$ and $C$ with non-negative entries and at least one element positive such that the matrix defined by

\begin{equation}
D := A + B + C
\end{equation}

is irreducible and all rows sums of $D$ are $0$. This should immediately exclude the matrix proposed by @MooS.

---

**Edit 2** Does the first edit imply that $A$ is actually irreducible so that $A$ is irreducibly diagonally dominant and non-singular as shown in the first sentence of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties)?

Comment: The base case of 1x1 matrices is trivial since it is simply a matrix containing one negative element. Since swapping two rows only makes the determinant switch signs and does not switch from non-zero to zero, we can swap the bottom row for one of the rows with sum less than $0$. We can then use induction to show that the lower-right hand (n-1)x(n-1) is non-singular since it satisfies all four properties. I'm not sure how to go from there to showing that the n by n matrix is non-singular.

Answer (score 5):

You need all row sums to be $<0$, else you can do the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

If you assume all row sums to be $<0$, the statement is true. After multiplying by $-1$, the matrix will be a [Diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that I am overlooking a condition, because this matrix should actually be excluded. I think the matrix $A$ is called a transient infinitesimal generator from the theory of Markov processes, if that rings any bells.